# Is @@ROWCOUNT preserved by EXECUTE or not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The [docs for @@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) say:

> EXECUTE statements preserve the previous @@ROWCOUNT.

I take this to mean that @@ROWCOUNT should have the same value after an EXECUTE statement that it had before.

However, considering the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #wat (id int);

INSERT #wat VALUES (1),(2),(3);

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT before;

EXECUTE('INSERT #wat VALUES (1),(2);');
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT after;

DROP TABLE #wat;
```

On SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU 8, `before` and `after` are different.

Do I misunderstand something here, or is this a documentation issue?

Comment: I think that statement is referring to `Natively compiled stored procedures`. Please refer following statement just before the `EXAMPLE` in the same `@@ROWCOUNT` documentation `Natively compiled stored procedures preserve the previous @@ROWCOUNT. Transact-SQL statements inside natively compiled stored procedures do not set @@ROWCOUNT.`

Answer (score 3):

I propose a different test for you to understand that doc statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestRowCount 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (1) name FROM sys.databases;
    SELECT TOP (6) name FROM sys.databases;
END
```

After you create this procedure, run this:

```
EXECUTE TestRowCount;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS Previous;
```

The `Previous` result is **6**. 
With that result it's easier to understand that  **EXECUTE statements preserve the previous @@ROWCOUNT** means the previous statement that was called by the `EXECUTE`.

In your example the `EXECUTE` called an statement that affected 2 rows, so it returned 2 instead of 3 (as you expected).